# How to determine, from LINUX, if a Windows server is running a specific program

Tags: linux, windows, odbc

I poll a Windows Server's ODBC database every 10 minutes from a Linux server. Whether or not the Windows program that updates the database is running, I obviously can get data - old data - back from the database.

But I need to be sure that the remote Windows application is actually running and updating the database.

How can I query the remote Windows server to see if the specific program is active?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the information you need via WMI, which linux can query with special packages.  the WMI namespace you need will be Win32_process, which will return a collection of process data, from there you can parse the data and work out if your app is running or not.  I've linked a linux wmi client below.

https://www.krenger.ch/blog/wmi-commands-from-linux/